# GAE Java local datastore overall size limit?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a set size limit on how large the datastore can be when testing a J/GAE app locally?  When playing around locally, my database seems to clear after it reaches about 200MB in size and I was curious if any set limits existed.  I am aware of scenarios in which the local datastore will clear itself such as between local dev server startups (if configured to do so), but I am seeing it clear mid way through usage.  I'm not asking for help on my problem specifically, rather the question about limits has me curious.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no limit for the local datastore file. However, I've never gotten this file to grow too much, to be able to tell for sure.

Since it's the local environment, this datastore is relatively small. I obviously don't have all the production data on the local hard drive, so the file mostly contains test data that it's easily manageable. I can see cases where having a lot of data might be desirable, but still I don't think it's a good idea to have too much.